# If Planet 9 is a primordial black hole with a mass of 5 Earth, is it possible to detect it in a ground telescope? What should we seek in this case?

Tags: black-hole, planet, solar-system

If planet 9 is not a planet but a black hole how can we find it? Can we see gravitational lense or infrared/gamma light?

Comment: I'd presume that microlensing events, if you looked in the right place at the right time, would be possible.

Comment: And for a sense of scale, we'd be talking about a BH roughly the size of a softball or large orange.

Comment: Its impossible to any blackhole if it is "silent". Although its still a tough job to detect supermassive blackholes, In your case difficulty of detecting a black hole of radius just 4.4 cm with an optical ground telescope depends on how far it is away from the sun. Gravitational lensing will help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would a small nearby black hole be detected and confirmed as such?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33535/how-would-a-small-nearby-black-hole-be-detected-and-confirmed-as-such)  See also: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27983/could-planet-nine-be-a-tiny-black-hole-or-an-exotic-compact-object-such-that-it and https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/36882/2531